# How to ONLY do the browser-default form validation upon submit?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, event-handling

I have a web form that extensively uses the HTML `type` attributes. I have to submit it in JSON, so I need to prevent the actual submitting, convert `FormData` to JSON, and POST it using AJAX.

The thing is, I don't feel like writing the data validation myself, and I don't think I wanna add more library for the validation either.

They're nothing too advanced, just `required` attributes, phone number, e-mail, numbers with certain increments, etc. I'd rather let the browser validate using its own mechanisms, and then when the time comes to submit, my script takes over.

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple actually. Depending on the type of input, each can be passed props to check like to making every field required, you just pass `required` to every input. `min`, `max` for numbers, `type="email"` to check emails, `maxLength`, `minLength` for string length checking etc. Make sure to pass the proper type too for each field. For more data, visit [Inputs explaination at W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp). Though, all the checks should be re-done in the backend for security purposes.